# how to secure sql server correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ive created a generic sql account for use with a bunch of old legacy apps.  I set the account to public and then tested by logging into sql server studio manager.  This was successful however i noticed that i was able to navigate into the system tables, look in the security folder etc etc.  How can i set up the account to not be able to do this.  I find it hard to believe that setting up an account and giving it the public role would allow access to these objects.  What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public account role is the least privileged role there is. If you remove the use from that role you might as well not allow it to connect at all.

You can go and remove user from all built in roles in user properties here

[image]

After that you can grant permissions explicitly using GRANT, DENY and other [security statements.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848791.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Being able to see the Security folder is not the same as being able to see the entries in the folder.  A user is typically able to see their own account, but not someone else's account.

Mapping a user to a database with a "public" role confers negligible power.  The "db_datareader" role typically allows table selects, but not (e.g.) stored procedure execution.  The "db_owner" role confers maximal power within the database.